# Viewing the "Replication" tab for a replicated folder target in the DFS "Namespaces" node in the 2008 DFS console says replication "not configured"

Tags: replication, dfs

On a server 2008 R2 box I setup a DFS folder folder in a namespace and then manually setup it up for replication in the "replication" node of the DFS console.

Now when I go to the "Replication" tab for the folder target in the "Namespaces" node it says "Replication Status: Not configured", but I checked replication for this folder is configured and it is working.

Googling around I found a post on a forum from someone with what appeared to be a similar problem on a 2003 R2 server. He was told the following:

(Link to forum post: http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/windows-server-dfs-and-frs/t-r2-dfs-namespacereplication-and-administration-possible-bug-or-by-design-362827.html)

```
"When a DFS Folder is configured to be replicated from the DFS Management UI 
or when a replicated folder is "published" to a DFS Namespace then the 
metadata for the replicated folder is tagged to show which DFS Namespace is 
it published in. It is this tag that the DFS Management tool searches when 
determining if a DFS Folder targets are replicated. If this tag does not 
exist then the UI does not know that the folder targets are being 
replicated. This is done mainly for performance reasons. Without this 
approach the UI would need to contact each individual folder target to 
determine its replication status before showing the folders in the UI. This 
would become extremely slow on any reasonably large DFS Namespace.

Please see the following KB article which gives some additional details and 
resolution steps: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=911255"
```

Following the above link I tried disabling and enabling both the folder targets and the replicated folders, but to no avail the tab still reports "not configured". I do not want to have to remove and re-create this DFS folder. How can I get the replication tab in the DFS Namespaces node of the DFS console to see that this folder is being replicated?

Answer (score 2):

I created one replication group through the GUI then created one via Powershell and ran into this problem.
`GetDfsReplicatedFolder` showed me each object, and the difference was in the `DfsnPath` attribute.
I then updated the 'missing' one using:

```
Set-DfsReplicatedFolder -GroupName $groupname -DfsnPath ("\\$domainfqdn\$namespace\$sharename")
```

and after a console refresh it became visible.

Comment: Excellent solution! The dash is missing in `Get-DfsReplicatedFolder`.